# Only allow Mousewheel event when shiftKey is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener, deck.gl

I am using Microsoft's Sanddance library in my app. It's a data visualizer/ chart library which allows the user to zoom in charts and explore data more closely, for example. I am using multiple charts on one page and I am having the issue that when a user wanted to scroll to the end of the page and his cursor was on a chart he/she would zoom in or out instead.

I would like to only allow zooming into the charts when the shiftKey is pressed meaning I would have to find a way to block the mousewheel event fired from `.deckgl-overlay`.

```
<div class='chart'>
  <div class='sanddance-root'>
    <div class='sanddance-gl'>
      <canvas class='deckgl-overlay'></canvas> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The canvas has the Mousewheel eventlistener attached to it. How could I block it from firing when shift is not pressed? Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you mentioned specifically, but you could add a mouse wheel listener to your canvas and call [`stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to prevent the event from bubbling.

Comment: You can not actually prevent events from firing based on such additional “conditions”. And since mouse and keyboard events are not really related, checking if shift _was_ currently pressed from inside the mousewheel handler, won’t be easy to achieve either. Could probably be done by using an additional keypress handler for the document, that then sets a boolean flag, that the wheel handler could access … But I am guessing the wheel handler we are talking about here was not added by yourself, but comes from the library?

Comment: Do you need the user to be able to interact with these charts in any _other_ way, than the scrolling? If not, then you could perhaps apply `pointer-events: none` to them, and only take that away, as long as shift is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I noticed that there is actually a `shiftKey` property on the 'mousewheel' event, so I think this won't be an issue. Indeed, the wheel handler was not added by myself but by the library. I need them to be able to 'drag' them around...